# Question regarding copying and pasting on exams

Tags: cheating, homework

On Wiley Plus, will students be able to copy and paste homework questions if not on a lock down browser? If so, can I detect that through any many means? I have been reprimanded before for not being critical on cheating, so I want to figure out any means I can use to minimize cheating among students. As a physics professor, I find it difficult for students to not look up their answers or have them not use a source like Chegg.

Comment: Already part of your other question.

Comment: I think there was a similar question in the last few days, you might want to have a look!